# Having multiple accounts logged in at once makes my laptop very slow and crashes

Tags: freeze, user-management

I am an Ubuntu user, and I decided to manage my laptop to use two accounts: one for personal use, and the other for work. If I switch accounts from one to other without terminating the session, the system is very slow and unresponsive, often forcing me to restart the machine. This seems very odd to me because the laptop has very good specs in terms of CPU and memory. How can I prevent this and be able to freely switch accounts without having to deal with the inconvenience of reopening all tabs and programs every time I come on and off work?

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
Host: Vivobook_ASUSLaptop X7600PC_N7 
Kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic 
Uptime: 15 days, 19 hours, 54 mins 
Packages: 2342 (dpkg), 32 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 4200x2625 
DE: GNOME 44.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-11370H (8) @  
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe 
Memory: 14383MiB / 15657MiB
```

Here are some misurations with `free -m`, taken at different times:

```
lunalavoro@luna-laptop:~$ free -m
               buff/cache condivisi gratuiti totali utilizzati disponibili
Mem:           15657       11295         281        3898        8303        4361
Swap:           2047           1        2046
lunalavoro@luna-laptop:~$ free -m
               buff/cache condivisi gratuiti totali utilizzati disponibili
Mem:           15657       14038         388        4850        6411        1618
Swap:           2047         148        1899
lunalavoro@luna-laptop:~$ free -m
               buff/cache condivisi gratuiti totali utilizzati disponibili
Mem:           15657       14416         574        5018        6016        1241
Swap:           2047         422        1625
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `free -m` in your question?

Comment: @vidarlo At what point should I include it? If it's right before the freese I find it quite difficult to get any output with my current knowledge.

Comment: With two sessions running.

Comment: Done, I added a couple of misuration: one at the start, and some others after opening my usual work apps (Firefox, VSCode)

Comment: Read `man free`. `free -h` will show how much RAM and swap you have, in `h`uman readable format

Comment: You could use `ps -ef` to see ALL processes. Read `man ps`.